# Call to a member function where() on string

Tags: php, laravel-5, error-handling, where-clause

im going to develop web with `laravel` framework. this is my code :

```
$valws = DB::table('layananpublik')->sum('value')->where('tahun',$tahun)->where('bulan',$stringbln)->where('kategori',$PilihKat);
```

and i get an error :

> FatalErrorException in JobHarianController.php line 195: Call to a
>   member function where() on string

Comment: you are using "sum" which should be in the last part of query, Ex: 'after all where conditions'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
$valws = DB::table('layananpublik')
       ->where('tahun', '=',$tahun)
       ->where('bulan', '=',$stringbln)
       ->where('kategori', '=',$PilihKat)
       ->sum('value');
```

OR

```
$valws = DB::table('layananpublik')
       ->select(DB::raw("SUM(value) as value")) 
       ->where('tahun', '=',$tahun)
       ->where('bulan', '=',$stringbln)
       ->where('kategori', '=',$PilihKat)
       ->get();
```

Comment: i have tried it on point 1 and there's no error. But why the result is nothing?

Comment: @ToshihikoYuta may be the conditions not satisfying

Comment: but if i use to count it the result is 0.